# Bound the difference between Spearman's Correlation and Kendall's Correlation

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

I am trying to prove or disprove that the difference between Spearman's Correlation and Kendall's Correlation is no more than 1 (or less, the tighter the merrier).

I am assuming there are no ties.

In an attempt to disprove the result using a counter example, I checked all possibilities for vectors with length 8. Got some pretty pictures but no counter example:
[image]

difference:

[image]

The difference is never more than 0.4 in this case, so I think it is true, but I was unable to prove it.

Comment: There is a very interesting post that could be a partial duplicate to your question. It is "Kendall Tau or Spearman's rho?  stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/kendall-tau-or-spearmans-rho .

Comment: For those who might want to tackle a direct algebraic approach, I believe the result can be obtained in two steps.  First (the key step), show that the extreme absolute value of the difference is attained for the data $$(1,n),(2,n-1),\ldots, (n,1),(n+1,2n),(n+2,2n-1),\ldots,(2n,n+1)$$ for $2n$ points and $$(1,n+1),(2,n),\ldots,(n+1,1),(n+2,2n+1),(n+3,2n),\ldots,(2n+1,n+2)$$ for $2n+1$ points.  Then just calculate the differences for these datasets. (In the first case there's another maximum and in the second case there are three other maxima implied by obvious symmetries.)

Comment: I came to say that I think the maximum absolute difference for odd $n$ is going to be $(n-2)/2n<\frac12$ but it looks like whuber has got rather further than I did (his suggestion seems to agree with that bound for odd $n$).

Comment: @Glen_b If I am correct, then the maximum absolute difference for data of length $n$ is $$\frac{2 (n-2) \left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil  \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor }{n \left(n^2-1\right)},$$ which has a limiting value of $1/2$ (from below) as $n\to\infty.$ That supports what you wrote.  This formula is related to [A111384](http://oeis.org/A111384), whose values are divided by $n(n^2-1)/4$.

Comment: That bound seems to match your formula for even n (and your limiting cases in the earlier comment certainly seem to match those obtained by exhaustive calculation for all the small $n$ values I could readily check - but I expect you already did that). It's interesting that the bound is 1/2. Did I make a mistake in the odd n case? (edit: No, I see now, I was right apart from manipulating your formula)

Comment: @Glen_b A *limit* of $1/2$ is intuitive: for the patterns I described, Spearman is close to $1/2$ while Kendall is $O(1/n)$. The algebra is simplified by generalizing my "crayon" approach to covariance.  Here's `R` code implementing the relevant formulas.  The arguments consist of two permutations of `1:n`. **Spearman**: `function(x, y) mean(outer(x, x, '-') * outer(y, y, '-')) * 6 / (length(x)^2 - 1)` **Kendall**: `function(x,y) mean(sign(outer(x, x, '-')) * sign(outer(y, y, '-'))) * (1 + 1/(length(x)-1))`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this [paper](http://www.ressources-actuarielles.net/ext/isfa/1226.nsf/9c8e3fd4d8874d60c1257052003eced6/70606dd23693cf69c1257827004cbe50/$FILE/rhotau.pdf)! And other works by these authors. I can't remember exactly where, but I have seen your first graph in their papers, and some proofs along with it. I think this can be done by leveraging copulas (as Kendall tau and Spearman rho can be written as a function of the underlying copula between the two variables). Hope it helps.

$C$ is the copula of $(X,Y). $

$$\tau(X,Y) = 4\int_0^1 \int_0^1 C(u,v) c(u,v)~\mathrm du\mathrm dv - 1$$

(Kendall correlation is the expectancy of the copula rescaled into $[0,1]$)

$$\rho(X,Y) = 12 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 C(u,v) ~\mathrm du\mathrm dv- 3.$$

Then, $|\tau - \rho| \leq \ldots$

Comment: The paper is a nice reference for the techniques it exhibits.  It does not, however, appear to contain a result that would easily imply the one conjectured in this question.  That is primarily because its results are not universal: they apply under various restrictive conditions and even then only in the limit as the joint distribution approaches independence.